# Highcharts : Combo-meteogram (DATA,XML/JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, highmaps

I want to modify this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-meteogram/) code.

I **don't** want to get data from **json/xml**, but I want to put it **manually** like this:

> this is a part of my code I didn't continued cause I lost it and it's complicated

```
{
        name: 'Air pressure',
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
        data: [1020.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1009.5, 1015.5, 1010.5, 1001.5, 1001.5],
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        shadow: false,
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' hPa'
        },
        dashStyle: 'shortdot',
        yAxis: 2
    }
```

For all things I want to get just 5 values for all data.

```
Datetime, Precipitation, Temperature, Air pressure ....
```

This is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series) of data entered manually, not from a server or somethings.

At the end, I want to do this to know where I can put my data because I have it but I don't know where I can put it.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of JavaScript code you can find function(xml).

Inside it you can write console.log(xml) and then check in console (Developer Tools) what is the structure of the data.

If you do want to change the code of the demo, then you would have to write your data in the same format.

You can look in code to see what exactly is needed, because not all data is used. Based on that you can disable ajax call and create data object manually.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qLynjzds/

Example of how data can look to work in the demo (2 points):

```
var xml = {
        credit: {
            link: {
                '@attributes': {
                    url: "http://www.yr.no/place/United_Kingdom/England/London/" //link for credits
                }
            }
        },
        location: {
            country: "Country",
            name: "City"
        },
        forecast: {
            tabular: {
                time: [{
                    '@attributes': {
                        from: "2015-05-28T14:00:00",
                        to: "2015-05-28T15:00:00"
                    },
                    symbol: {
                        '@attributes': {
                            'var': "01d",
                            name: "Clear sky"
                        },
                    },
                    temperature: {
                        '@attributes': {
                            value: "17"
                        },
                    },
                    precipitation: {
                        '@attributes': {
                            value: "0"
                        },
                    },
                    windDirection: {
                        '@attributes': {
                            deg: "252.6",
                            name: "West"
                        },
                    },
                    windSpeed: {
                        '@attributes': {
                            mps: "16.6",
                            name: "Strong breeze"
                        },
                    },
                    pressure: {
                        '@attributes': {
                            value: "1013.8"
                        },
                    }
                }, {
                    '@attributes': {
                        from: "2015-05-28T15:00:00",
                        to: "2015-05-28T16:00:00"
                    },
                    symbol: {
                        '@attributes': {
                            'var': "01d",
                            name: "Clear sky"
                        },
                    },
                    temperature: {
                        '@attributes': {
                            value: "15"
                        },
                    },
                    precipitation: {
                        '@attributes': {
                            value: "1"
                        },
                    },
                    windDirection: {
                        '@attributes': {
                            deg: "252.6",
                            name: "West"
                        },
                    },
                    windSpeed: {
                        '@attributes': {
                            mps: "16.6",
                            name: "Strong breeze"
                        },
                    },
                    pressure: {
                        '@attributes': {
                            value: "1010.8"
                        },
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    };
```